# How to install printer driver from terminal in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

Install Canon Printerdriver LBP7010C on ubuntu 22.04

Is it even possible to use this Canon F166400 anymore with newest Ubuntu software. When I was using Ubuntu 16.04 I could use this driver for LBP7010C, but it was a struggle to get to work, and I have simply forgotten how I did it. With the newest Ubuntu 22.04 is it even possible to use this driver or printer.
I have downloaded this driver file "linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz" but I can't find out how to install it?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** From what I was able to find, the Canon F166400 is the same as the Canon i-SENSYS LBP6030. [The Canon driver for Linux is available on their website (UK), updated in 2019](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer/products/printers/i-sensys/lbp-series/i-sensys-lbp6030.html?type=drivers&detailId=tcm:14-1156622&os=all&productTcmUri=tcm:14-1188954). That would seem a promising avenue to pursue (if support for that printer is not already available in CUPS).

Comment: Thank  you very much @richbl, I was able to install the printer with Canon i-SENSYS LBP6030, you saved my day.

Comment: glad to hear. Not sure why this question was closed, but I've asked the moderators to reopen as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Thank you very much for your comment @richbl, I was able to install the printer with Canon i-SENSYS LBP6030, you saved my day.

Download the driver from [here](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer/products/printers/i-sensys/lbp-series/i-sensys-lbp6030.html?type=drivers&detailId=tcm:14-1156622&os=all&productTcmUri=tcm:14-1188954), extract it, and run `sudo bash ./install.sh`